# How to understand the "lpStartAddress"-Parameter of the function CreateThread

Tags: assembly, c

I have the following assembly code :

```
.....
lea eax, [ebp+ThreadID]
push eax              ; lpThreadID
push 0                ; dwCreationFlags
push 0                ; lpParameter
push offset StartAddress  ; lpStartAddress
push 0                ; dwStackSize
call CreateThread
....
```

So, I try to translate it in a C-like pseudocode:

```
DWORD* LPWORD eax_lpThreadID = NULL;
DWORD dwCreationFlags;
void *LPVOID lpParameter;
SIZE_T dwStackSize;
LPSECURITY ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes;

HANDLE handle_to_new_Thread = CreateThread(lpThreadAttributes, dwStackSize, ..., lpParameter, dwCreationFlags, eax_lpThreadID );
```

As you can see, I do not include the 3rd parameter, namely the parameter `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress`, because I have problems understanding it.
In [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472837/what-is-a-lpthread-start-routine) i have read that a `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` is a function pointer defined as:

```
typedef DWORD (__stdcall *LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) (
  [in] LPVOID lpThreadParameter
);
```

That would mean that the 4th parameter `lpThreadParameter` is a parameter of this. 
But how can I integrate that information into my pseudo C code program ?
I am little bit confused about that. Can someone explain it to me? The other attributes/parameters are clear....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C pseudocode let's say you have a function called `doJob`. You want to create a thread to executes it.

```
DWORD WINAPI doJob(LPVOID lpParameter){
    // Do some work. You can only pass one parameter.
    // If you need more parameters, define a structure
    // and send it though it's pointer.
    return statuscode;
}

Handle hThread = 
   CreateThread(&attributes,dwStackSize,&doJob,&paramstruct,flags,&newThreadIdBuffer);
```

Or in asm (nasm syntax, if I still remember it):

```
lea eax, newThreadIdBuffer
push eax
push 0 ; or 4 or 0x00010000 or 0x00010004
lea eax, paramstruct
push eax
lea eax, doJob
push eax
push dwStackSize ; 0 will use default
lea eax, attributes
push eax
call CreateThread
```

This can be done cleaner, but I believe it demonstrates the concept.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx)

> **lpStartAddress** is a pointer to the application-defined function to be
>   executed by the thread. This pointer represents the starting address
>   of the thread.

Basically `lpStartAddress` is the entry point of the thread. This is a callback function. It will be called when the thread is created and executed.

More on this,

> The CreateThread function creates a new thread for a process. The
>   creating thread must specify the starting address of the code that the
>   new thread is to execute. Typically, the starting address is the name
>   of a function defined in the program code (for more information, see
>   ThreadProc). This function takes a single parameter and returns a
>   DWORD value. A process can have multiple threads simultaneously
>   executing the same function.

See *[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516(v=vs.85).aspx)* page, for an example on creating threads.

Answer (score 2):

```
lea eax, [ebp+ThreadID]
push eax              ; lpThreadID
push 0                ; dwCreationFlags
push 0                ; lpParameter
push offset StartAddress  ; lpStartAddress
push 0                ; dwStackSize
call CreateThread
```

the first argument is pushed last so you have got it all reversed up also it seems during copy paste you missed one argument lpSecurtiyAttributes

cpp

```
Handle hThread = CreateThread(&lpThreadId,NULL,NULL,&lpStartAddress,NULL,NULL);
```